# How to fix the output I am getting with a multiple condition If statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a couple If statements with multiple conditions that I am wanting to do a simple Calculation with but I am unable to workout the output. I think the issue is related to the data types.

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()
Dim Transmit As Boolean
Dim StartTime As String
Dim EndTime As String
Dim RunTime As String
Dim messagebox As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
'conditions for startTime
While EtiLoggingNEW.Cells(i + 12, 1) = "Time"
    If (EtiLoggingNEW.Cells(i + 12, 6) = "Active" And EtiLoggingNEW.Cells(i + 12, 8) = "False" And Transmit = False) Then
        Transmit = True
        StartTime = EtiLoggingNEW.Cells(i + 12, 2)
    End If
    'conditions for endTime
    If ((EtiLoggingNEW.Cells(i + 12, 6) = "Standby" Or EtiLoggingNEW.Cells(i + 12, 6) = "Shutdown" Or EtiLoggingNEW.Cells(i + 12, 8) = "True") And Transmit = True) Then
        EndTime = EtiLoggingNEW.Cells(i + 12, 2)
        'Print EndTime, EtiLoggingNEW.Cells(i + 12, 15).Value
        Transmit = False
    End If

    RunTime = (EndTime - StartTime) * 86400

    messagebox = MsgBox(RunTime, vbOKOnly)
    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

What I want to happen is to print RunTime into the message box (or ideally into  column 15). Currently the messagebox returns blank with only the vbaOK button.

Edited for code readability...

Comment: print is not a valid vba statement, Also, qualify all your Cells and Range references with the parent worksheet name. And yes, your time should be of a different datatype e.g. date.

Comment: I originally had the sheet name .Cells  but it was giving me an object required error. I have commented out the print function as i am trying to work out the message box return currently

Comment: @QHarr Just to clarify, [Print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/printstatement) ***is*** a valid VBA statement - just not like that.

Comment: @Comintern  correct. Apologise. I’m not sure have ever tried using outside immediate window

Comment: As @QHarr mentioned, you need to change the datatypes of `StartTime`, `Endtime`, and `Runtime` to `Date` rather than `String`.

Comment: I think you can use: Debug.Print

Comment: @DavidN I have changed the data types from strings to Date. the message box is now returning 00:00:00

Comment: @GreenerGreen, have you confirmed that the two values in the cells it's pulling for `StartTime` and `EndTime` are actually different?  Perhaps 0 is the correct value in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I try to shorten the code. any suggestions? @QHarr @Comintern

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()

    Dim Transmit As Boolean
    Dim StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date
    Dim RunTime As Long, i As Long

    i = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EtiLoggingNEW")
        While .Cells(i + 12, 1) = "Time"
            If (.Cells(i + 12, 6) = "Active" And .Cells(i + 12, 8) = "False" And Transmit = False) Then
                Transmit = True
                StartTime = .Cells(i + 12, 2)
            End If

            If ((.Cells(i + 12, 6) = "Standby" Or .Cells(i + 12, 6) = "Shutdown" Or .Cells(i + 12, 8) = "True") And Transmit = True) Then
                EndTime = .Cells(i + 12, 2)
                Debug.Print EndTime
                    .Cells(i + 12, 15).Value = EndTime
                Transmit = False
            End If

            RunTime = (EndTime - StartTime) * 86400

            MsgBox RunTime, vbOKOnly

            i = i + 1

        Wend

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the updated code. it seems to run through fine however the message box is returning 0 each time im unsure if thats becuase the times are actually dates as in they are formatted in DD/HH/YYYY HH/MM